# How to split line breaks \n into <li> tags in AlpineJS

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, alpine.js

I'm using Alpine.js to fetch API calls.

JSON

```
{"items":[

{"title":"Title here","url":"https://example.com","terms":"Line 1 here.\nLine 2 here.\nLine 3 here."},
{"title":"Title here","url":"https://example.com","terms":"Line 1 here.\nLine 2 here.\nLine 3 here."}

],
"status":"success",
"message":"OK",
"code":0
}
```

I use `<template x-for="item in items">` to display all records and I'd like to split line breaks into `<li></li>` inside `<ul></ul>`

I write a new function:

```
      lines(text) {
        const line = text.split('\n');
        let lines = "";
        for (let i = 0; i < line.length; i++) {
          lines += "<li>" + line[i] + "</li>";
        }
        return lines;
      }
```

and I use it in HTML

```
<template x-for="item in items">
    <ul x-text="lines(item.terms)">
    </ul>
    <p x-text="item.description"></p>
</template>
```

By using x-text, the function shows `<li></li>` as text too.

```
<ul>
"<li>Line 1 here</li>
<li>Line 2 here</li>"
</ul>
```

Please let me know how to make it works. I'm not a pro coder, just building my personal website. I'd like to fetch API, show records with a load-more button or pagination, a few filters e.g. `<select>` and an instant input, but I cannot find something like that. If you have any JS script (vanilla JS or Alpine.js preferred), please share it with me. I myself cannot write the complete code without sample. Thanks for your anwser!

Answer (score 0):

The [`x-text` directive](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/text) expect simple strings. If you want to provide HTML you have to use the [`x-html` directive](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/html). To avoid [XSS vulnerabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) we can combine it with `x-text` so Alpine.js will escape any leftover HTML content. We just need to embed `line[i]` into a string literal:

```js
function lines(text) {
  const line = text.split("\n");
  let lines = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < line.length; i++) {
    lines += '<li x-text="`' + line[i] + '`"></li>';
  }
  return lines;
}
```

```html
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
<div x-data='{items:[
  {"title":"Title here","url":"https://example.com","terms":"Line 1 here.\nLine 2 here.\nLine 3 here."},
  {"title":"Title here","url":"https://example.com","terms":"Line 1 here.\nLine 2 here.\nLine 3 here."}
  ]}'>

  <template x-for="item in items">
    <ul x-html="lines(item.terms)">
    </ul>
  </template>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about XSS. It works well as expected!